# How to make a html table using python?

Tags: python, html

Just received a task from a basic programming course in uni.
I am a complete newbie regarding computers. I am a freshman and have no prior programming experience.

The task requires making a python source code that would print a html table as output.
No use of modules is allowed.

We covered some basic python things like if, for loop, while, print, etc... 
but didn't learn anything about creating html in python.

I've been searching on the internet for hours and hours, but all solutions seem so advanced and they all involve use of third-party modules, which in my case is not allowed.

Professor knows that we are all complete newbies, so there's got to be a way to do this without much professional knowledge.

Can anyone please tell me the basics of making a html table in python?

Like do I just type in things like

```
<tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
```

in python? Basically have no idea where to start.

** The code should be written in a way that when it is executed in bash shell ($ python file_name.py), it prints out a html table.

P.S. I'm using vs code as an editor for python.

Comment: What is the desired output??? An html file or html code in console?

Comment: ...or HTML output from python cgi... And is it supposed to print out an empty table, should it be fixed or take number of rows and columns as parameters... or should you express some data as a HTML table... This question is a) too broad b) homework.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to be able to help, you need to be more specific about what is the input, what is the wanted output and what have you tried to do already. Otherwise, the question is too broad and can't be addressed properly.

Comment: the code should be written in a way that when it is executed in bash shell ($ python file_name.py), it prints out a html table.

Answer (score 0):

As I can imagine the only way to make it simple without going bananas is to write
html file. So basically its .write rows into html file using python. If this is what you want - here is an example how to do that plain and simple:

```
from random import randint
with open('table.html', 'w') as html:
    html.write('<table style="border:2px solid black;">\n')
    for i in range(5):
        html.write('<tr>\n')
        for i in range(3):
            html.write(f'<td>{randint(10,150)}</td>\n')
        html.write('</tr>\n')
    html.write('</table>')
```

"\n" - used to make you Html document look readable.
Random.randint module is used to generate data - its basic simple module just for data placeholders.
For the table to look nice you can add border to td -

```
<td style="border:2px solid black;" >(random data)</td>
```

It will look like solid html/excel table.

Comment: I also think the only way would be actually writing a html file. But would it be possible to do that without using random.randint, since I want to do this without using modules?

Comment: @flora As @EakzIT said, `random.randint()` is only used to fill the table with bogus data, which you can see, when you look at the code example he posted.

Answer (score -1):

You won't learn anything by copy-pasting working examples that you don't understand and you can't expect to understand anything, when you search for solutions to complex problems without knowing the basics.

Given the level of experience you have according to your question, you should instead search for a Python [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to get a grip of the language. Read about the synthax, Python's object model and the type hierarchy. With that knowledge you will be able to understand the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), and with that, you should be able to solve your problem without searching for pre-made solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but surely I wasn't looking for ready-made answers when I posted the question. After posting this, I spent whole day thinking about the task and how to solve it, searched for some useful information online, and then realized that the given task is quite simple. It's just that I've been overthinking it.

Comment: As we haven't covered any HTML-related topic in class yet, doing the task doesn't require much complex solution. It looks like the task can be done just by using for loop, lists, if, print... etc, all of which I've already learned and am quite confident with. I'm now almost finished with the task, which I did on my own without copy-pasting.

Comment: I definitely should've spent more time thinking about the problem before I could post anything. I didn't even fully understand the task when I posted this, so that's definitely a fault on my part. I'll try to be more thoughtful next time I post anything.

Comment: @flora You don't need to justify your question. :) I was just trying to help by pointing out why all the hours you searched probably didn't yield any useful results. In Python, all functionality besides the most basic is provided by modules, and if you aren't allowed to import anything, the built-in data-types, `open()` and `print()` is everything you can work with.

Answer (score -1):

As we haven't covered any HTML-related topic in class yet, doing the task doesn't require much complex solution. It looks like the task can be done just by using for loop, lists, if, print... etc, all of which I've already learned and am quite confident with. Many thanks to everyone who cared to give help and answers.

Comment: It had to, because nothing else is available without any modules.